# Метод элемента WebBrowser, который определяет есть подключение к интернету или нет?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser

Разрабатываю свой браузер(типо хрома и тд). Не знаю какой метод элемента webBrowser отвечает за текущее состояние подключения(есть или нет).

Comment: С обычный пинг вышел с моды?

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "подключение к интернету"? Вам нужно проверить доступность какого-то адреса? Отправьте на него запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В WebBrowser нет метода для определения доступности интернета, вам нужно сделать свой метод для определения.

Вариант 1:
Сделать тестовый запрос. (не желательно использовать перед каждым запросом страницы)

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (client.OpenRead("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:
Взять состояние подключения к интернету из системы.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll")]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
     int desc;
     return InternetGetConnectedState(out desc, 0);         
}
```

Comment: Варианты не дают никаких гарантий. Например, гугл может быть доступен, но будет не доступен тот ресурс, который требуется в приложении, потому что его заблокировал провайдер/администратор/роскомнадзор/упал сервер/и т.д.